# N-bonacci cipher

Tags: mathematics, cipher

Encoded text:

> 9, 15, 15, 16, 25, 6, 11, 2, 9, 6, 11, 2, 21, 1, 14, 9, 19, 23, 25, 17, 19, 18, 1

Hint 1:

> Look up n-bonacci

Hint 2:

> Starting numbers are different

Hint 3:

> Message length is the same as encoded length

Hint 4 (slightly changed):

> All the numbers are in a certain range. What is the modulo for that range?

Hint 5

> This cipher has no key.

Hint 6 (basically gives it away)

> n-bonacci starting numbers are the message.

Hint 7 (literally just describes the encryption algorithm)

> Start with the letter values of the message, and repeat as many times as there are letters in the message: Change the current letter values to the values except the first, and then the sum of the values, including the first, mod 26.
>  In code: `for _ in range(len(message)): message = message[1:] + sum(message) % 26`

I will add more if it is not solved soon.

Hints are in no particular order, but some might be less helpful than others.

Notes:

This will probably be very tedious without computers, so they are allowed. The message is all lowercase letters, with no spaces, but it is more than one word.

Comment: Perhaps, individual numbers can be comma separated,  rather than by currently used space for better clarity.

Comment: is the message a common phrase?

Comment: Computers allowed or not?

Comment: It is not a common phrase, and computers are allowed.

Comment: “Message length is the same as encoded length” Is that the quantity of individual numbers or digits?

Comment: @Ambo100 Numbers

Comment: Upper AND Lower case letters...no numbers in the solution?

Comment: is the message more than one word?

Comment: @Drt It is multiple words.

Comment: Would a Caesar de/cipher be a waste of time with this?

Comment: @drt Yup. The main puzzle here is to figure out the encryption method.

Comment: If it isn't a version of  Caesar cipher then you will have to give me a good hint.  I have looked at most other approaches that look like this

Comment: @drt Google "n-bonacci" + hint 2 is important

Comment: i looked into the n-bonnaci series stuff and all solutions i come up with diverge away from your apparent series unless it is something like a penta-bonacci.   a uni-bonnaci doesnt work either but it looks like it should be

Comment: Coded a solution yesterday, best I got was egg<something> But it's still jumbled text. Reviewed the hints, revised my code, still can't wrap my mind around it.

Comment: @adib Can I see your code, to check if it is doing the right thing?

Comment: @pycoder Here you go: https://repl.it/OGus/0

Comment: Wild guess here...is this some sort of binary heap that you set up with the modulo for the range being the root and we need to write pointers to pull characters from the heap?  Otherwise why are you asking about the modulo?  I have run as many n-bonacci type attacks as I can barf up and nothing comes out looking legible as numbers?

Answer (score 3):

The message is

> CONGRATULATIONSYOUGOTIT

though really

> not much congratulation is in order for simply inverting the algorithm OP has kindly provided :-).

Algorithm:

> once per number in the list: compute last number minus sum of others, mod 26, put that at the start of the list, and drop the last one. (This is just doing the encoding algorithm in reverse.)

Remark:

> although no one got this until the answer was more or less handed to us on a plate, I don't think it was particularly unreasonable; there are only so many things to try and this should have been one of the earlier ones. On the other hand, I did spend a little while staring at it earlier when there weren't so many hints, and this *wasn't* one of the things I thought of trying :-).